# Objects, prototypal inheritance, and a failing function

Tags: javascript, function, object

While trying to move on to some intermediate/advanced Javascript concepts, I've run into a problem. In the following code, the object prototype and created objects seem to be functioning fine. But when I try to then use them in the function 'winner', the result always declares the winner as the second argument passed, regardless of their score. Here, Mike has a higher score(395) than Peter (206) and should be declared the winner. Also, the console is logging the message "Peter wins with a score of function () {
            return (this.age * 5) + this.height;
        }".

Any help understanding what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var player = {
    name: 'Default',
    age: 'Default',
    height: 'Default',
    score: function() {
        return (this.age * 5) + this.height;
    }
}
    
var Mike = Object.create(player);
Mike.name = 'Mike';
Mike.age = 67;
Mike.height = 60;


var Peter = Object.create(player);
Peter.name = 'Peter';
Peter.age = 30;
Peter.height = 56;


var winner = function(player1, player2) {
    var player1score = player1.score;
    var player2score = player2.score;
    
    if(player1score > player2score) {
        console.log(player1.name + ' wins with a score of ' + player1.score);
    } else {
        console.log(player2.name + ' wins with a score of ' + player2.score);
    }
}

winner(Mike, Peter);
winner(Peter, Mike);
```

Comment: Since score is a function, you'll want to call it like this: `player1.score()`

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
var player1score = player1.score;
var player2score = player2.score;
```

with

```
var player1score = player1.score();
var player2score = player2.score();
```

You have to call the function, if you just write `player1.score` you will get the body of the function.

Comment: Dumb mistake. I knew it would be something little like this. Thanks!